# What is the best way of writing test case for function which is in loop

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

I want to write a testcase but that function is in loop

```
def myfunction():
   for file in files:
      myfun(file, Temp=True)
```

Comment: You need to give more detail about the question and the problem encountered.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Actually i have a simple function and in it I am just calling a another function but in loop. Now I want to write a test case for this function?

Comment: The fact that this function is hard to test points to bad design. If `files` was a parameter, you could simply mock out `myfun` and check it got called the right number of times. You should then separately test the (unmocked!) `myfun`.

Answer (score 1):

One important thing to understand here is that, you dont need to test the loop. What you need to do is test the function itself.

Thus write a test that tests `myfun`. Later on you can add more tests depending on the type of files that `myfun` is expected to handle.

Comment: But how i can test my function, I thought I will use assert call with but my param is change in every iteration. Can you please give one small example How I can write it?

Comment: You dont need to test `myfunction` if all it does is call `myfun` in a loop. I say so, because, once you have tests for `myfun`, you will know if `myfunction` is not working as intended because your tests for `myfun` will start failing in that case.

Comment: That's just not true. If you refactor `myfunction` to simply `pass` it will be broken, but `myfun`'s tests won't tell you that.

Comment: Agreed. That's why I said: `You dont need to test myfunction if all it does is call myfun in a loop.` ; Ofcourse it would need tests if it does something different or in addition to what OP has defined `myfunction` as.

Comment: And I'm saying you're wrong - even trivial functions should be unit tested (and their triviality generally makes them easy to test, which is nice!) If you subscribe to TDD, you shouldn't even have written the function prior to writing a test that fails in its absence.

Answer (score 1):

If what you wanna test is really `myfunction`, the simplest way is to replace the hardcoded call to `myfun` by a callback, ie

```
def myfunction(callback=myfun):
     files = whatever()
     for f in files:
         callback(f, temp=True)
```

Then you can pass anything you want as callback for your tests.